# Java repeat operation with different operators

Tags: java, operators

I am working on an encryption code for my homework and I wish to add, subtract, multiply and divide every other letter. For example "This is a message". I would like to add "T" to the key, subtract "h" from the key, multiply "i" by the key and divide "s" by the key.

I am wondering if there is a way to change the operator instead of repeating the same block of code 4 times?

Here is the part of code I wish to repeat:

The + I want to swap for - * /

```
        newletters[x]=(char) (letters[x]+key[x]);
```

And this is the rest of the method:

```
public static void LetterChange(){
    int x=0;
    int tocarry;
    int newkey;
    newletters=new char[size];
    for (int count=0; (sizeofstring/4)>count; count++){
//ADDITION
        newletters[x]=(char) (letters[x]+key[x]);        
//If character too big
        if (newletters[x]>126){
            tocarry=(int)newletters[x]-127;
            newletters[x]=(char) (33+tocarry);
        }
//If character too small
        if (newletters[x]<33){
            tocarry=(int)33-newletters[x];
            newletters[x]=(char) (127-tocarry);
        }
        x=x+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify - you wish to cycle through the operators? So the first, fifth, ninth etc characters will have the corresponding key character added to them, the second, sixth and tenth characters have the key character subtracted from them, etc?

Comment: how could you "multiply" two letters for example?

Comment: I converted the string to a char array and then you can multiply it by an integer.

Comment: helper function that takes in the operator as an argument by using an enum

Comment: Can you explain how to use a helper function as I have never come across one before.

Comment: @Nightfortress a helper function is not to be mean a helper basically, its only function is to do one function that is repeated to help the calling function not having to keep doing the same code copy and pasted every where.

Comment: Just an observation: you're dividing a char by some value - and what happens when that char value is uneven, for example 65? You'll get 32 because you're using integer division. So how will you ever "decode" 32 back into 65 again?

Comment: @BadCash Thanks for pointing that out guess I'll just have to use add, subtract and relocating letters then. Unless anyone else could find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Using `ScriptEngine` should do the trick.
`ScriptEngine` takes a mathematical expression as a string as solves it

But truth to be told this looks like a hacky solution
But anyways this works. *Tried and Tested*.

Import

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
```

Code

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
char[] oper={'+','-','*','/'};
for(char c:oper)
    System.out.println(engine.eval("3"+c+"2"));
```

Comment: if i understand this correctly, it doesn't seem very efficient since you will have O(4) N times where another operation that is constant is O(1) N times.

Comment: No, It will still be O(1) N times. I didn't reply to OP's code i only gave a general of how it can be done. How it is do be done is entirely upon OP. Mine was only an example. If  needed (if someone asks me for it) i can implement my solution in OP's code to show how it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Change your method signature to:

```
public static void letterChange(IntBinaryOperator op)
```

Modify the line you want to repeat like this:

```
newletters[x] = (char) op.applyAsInt(letters[x], key[x]);
```

Call the new method with the operator you like, for example:

```
letterChange((c1, c2) -> c1 + c2);
letterChange((c1, c2) -> c1 * c2);
letterChange((c1, c2) -> c1 - c2);
letterChange((c1, c2) -> c1 / c2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java **doesn't** support user defined operator overloading. If you have multiple code occurrences where you need to perform these operations, consider moving them to a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do something like this:

```
    for (int x=0; x<sizeofstring; x++){
        switch( x % 2 ){
            case 0: newletters[x]=(char) (letters[x]+key[x]); break;
            case 1: newletters[x]=(char) (letters[x]-key[x]); break;                
        }

        //If character too big
        if (newletters[x]>126){
            tocarry=(int)newletters[x]-127;
            newletters[x]=(char) (33+tocarry);
        }

        //If character too small
        if (newletters[x]<33){
            tocarry=(int)33-newletters[x];
            newletters[x]=(char) (127-tocarry);
        }
    }
```

This way letter 1 will use +, letter 2 will use -, letter 3 will use +, letter 4 will use -, etc.

Notice I removed * and /. We already discussed / in the comment of the question, and * I fear will give you values way more than 127, which means your "error correction" will not be able to correct them.